# Sentencia SQL con INNER JOIN para halar una columna de dos tablas en Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, join

Necesito ayuda con una sentencia SQL. No he trabajado nunca con INNER JOIN y no logro hacerla correctamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver en la imagen anterior, lo que busco es esto:

1. Guardar el `id_invitacion` de la tabla `invitacion`
2. Reemplazar `id_invitado` con `nombre` de la tabla `invitado`, es
   decir, en lugar de guardar el `id_invitado`, quiero recibir el
   String que se encuentra en la columna `nombre`
3. Reemplazar `id_evento` con la tabla `evento`, es decir, en lugar de guardar el `id_evento`, quiero recibir el String que se encuentra en la columna `nombre`

Para guardar los datos, tengo este código:

```
int i = 0;
do {
    registros[i][0] = rs.getInt("id_invitacion");
    registros[i][1] = rs.getString("nombreEvento");
    registros[i][2] = rs.getString("nombreInvitado");
    i++;
} while (rs.next());
```

Hasta ahora esta es la sentencia que he creado pero, no me funciona:

```
sSQL = "SELECT evento.nombre AS nombreEvento FROM evento "
                + ", invitado.nombre AS nombreInvitado FROM invitado "
                + "INNER JOIN invitacion ON evento.id_evento = invitacion.id_invitado "
                +"WHERE evento.nombre LIKE '%" + buscar + "%' ORDER BY id_invitacion";
```

Error que recibo:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax

Cualquier ayuda será bien recibida.

Comment: @Robert: Un consejo, siempre es buena idea de especificar el error preciso que recibes. Simplemente decir que algo no te funciona no es lo ideal.

Comment: @sstan vale gracias, he editado la respuesta con el error que recibo.

Comment: Bueno, admito que el error en este caso no es muy útil :). Bueno, espero que la respuesta que te dejé te sirva.

Comment: @RobertGomez te marca el error porque utilizas doblemente la sentencia  `FROM` Utiliza la respuesta del compañero @sstan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como ya sospechabas, la forma cómo haces los joins en tu consulta SQL no es válida. Es más, no veo que estés devolviendo la columna `id_invitacion`. Aquí te dejo la versión corregida (nota: `inner join` y `join` son equivalentes):

```sql
select invitacion.id_invitacion,
       evento.nombre as nombreEvento,
       invitado.nombre as nombreInvitado
  from evento
  join invitacion
    on invitacion.id_evento = evento.id_evento
  join invitado
    on invitado.id_invitado = invitacion.id_invitado
 where evento.nombre like '%buscar_cadena_aquí%'
 order by invitacion.id_invitacion
```

Adicionalmente, no deberías usar un bucle `do-while`, porque al hacer esto, estarás tratando de leer información de registros antes de ejecutar `rs.next()`, lo que no es legal y te va a dar error. Mas bien, usa un bucle `while` normal:

```
int i = 0;

while (rs.next()) {
    registros[i][0] = rs.getInt("id_invitacion");
    registros[i][1] = rs.getString("nombreEvento");
    registros[i][2] = rs.getString("nombreInvitado");
    i++;
}
```

Comment: se te fue una "," en `invitado.nombre as nombreInvitado,`

Comment: @Cig: Buen ojo, gracias!

Comment: Vale!!, muchas gracias hermano, nunca iba a poder lograrlo, aunque sigo sin entender el significado de todas esas uniones pero hay vamos, de poco a poco. Tengo una última duda, al hacer el cambio del do while{} a while{} se me ha generado en el JTable una fila extra vacía al final, como podría arreglarlo?, por alguna razón me esta cargando una fila vacía, sin valores. Screenshot: http://oi65.tinypic.com/2psefrn.jpg

Comment: No te sabría decir. Te sugiero de hacer una pregunta separada que incluya un poco mas del código envuelto para poder diagnosticar bien este otro problema.

Comment: vale. Gracias hermano, no sabes el favor que me has hecho, tengo pocos  días trabajando con SQL pero, con sentencias sencillas, no tan complicadas como esa. Tienes algún link para poder entender cómo se arma todo eso?, trato de entender lo que hiciste pero no entiendo el significado de = y los puntos y las comas :(

Comment: Puedes probar estudiando el enlace siguiente: [Join](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join). La explicación es buena. Vale la pena tomar el tiempo de absorber ese nuevo concepto. Te va a servir mucho. Si aun te quedan dudas, o puedes abrir otra pregunta específica a tu duda, o puedes dejar una nota. Tal vez podamos aclarar tus dudas en el chat. Pero ahora se me acabó el tiempo.